# Rails 4 - Uploading multiple images like these examples (Paperclip installed already)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, carrierwave

I already have Paperclip installed and at the moment it uploads just one picture that appear on the show page.

I want to allow users to post up to x images, but at least one img is required. I'd like it to be a Jquery slider (with arrows to go to the next picture) or like this example on Craigslist:

[image]
I've only been doing Rails for about two weeks,

Namely, user can drag n drop or choose multiple images from their local computer.

I've only been learning Rails for about 2 weeks, so if you can point to anything on Railscasts or Youtube, it would be a lot more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can begin by making an `Image`model where it `belongs_to` a `user` and a `user` `has_many  :images`. The `Image` model can have attribute `image` that's an attachment from `paperclip`. You can then put validations on the associations which will allow you to have minimum 1 image etc.

Comment: I currently have an Article controller that has the associations and validations. You're saying I should add has_many :images to that? Or create a new Image model? Right now it just has validations (image type, size, etc)

Comment: You can create a new `Image` model and move the image type, size, etc, over and use validation on the association in the `Article` model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build that by your own (which might be a little heavy for a beginner) you should have a look on the following

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload (youll find somewhere else, but i dont post those links)

for me it sounds like thats exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having A LOT of problem implementing it in my current code :/

Comment: I've tried watching Railscast on this, I'm also using Carrierwave, but while its letting me chose multiple files, it's not showing it...

Comment: Im sure you have more Trouble doin by yorself. Actually you can Download the Source of an Episode of railscast at github. Just clone the git and explore how its working.